# Render base64 code as image in Laravel Backpack CRUD view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-backpack

Is there a way to render image directly from base64 code in Laravel backpack CRUD view without converting it to image file?

My reason for this is to not consume disk space. I tried viewing the documentation but only the saving of the base64 code is shown.

Thanks.

--edit--

I already have this code on my CRUD controller:

```
$this->crud->addColumn([ // base64_image
                'label' => "Signature",
                'name' => "signature_data",
                'filename' => NULL, // set to null if not needed
                'type' => 'base64_image',
                'aspect_ratio' => 0, // set to 0 to allow any aspect ratio
                'crop' => false, // set to true to allow cropping, false to disable
                'src' => NULL, // null to read straight from DB, otherwise set to model accessor function
        ]);
```

`signature_data` field is set to `LONGBLOB`

But it only displays the base64 code in the CRUD view:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change signature field in CRUD view file:

```
<td>
<img src="{{signature field name here}}" width="100" height="100"/>
</td>
```

Comment: is this a custom view file? it seems that I cant find it on the built-in view file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default `base64_image` column type in Backpack ([all columns here in docs](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.6/crud-columns#image)). So Backpack just treated your column type as `text`. Since it's a "text" column, it shows the first characters of your blob.

You can [create a custom column type](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.6/crud-columns#creating-a-custom-column-type) that shows your image from the base64 string. Consider re-using the `image.blade.php` file - Backpack does have an `image` column type that shows images from an URL.

**Background:** There have been talks regarding a `base64_image` column type some time ago - some suggested adding it in the core (because it would be intuitive), others motioned against it, because we should *probably* discourage people from storing images as base64 strings in the database. I'm still torn, but leaning towards having it. If you do create the column type for yourself, consider submitting a PR with it - that way the discussion is reopened and we might include it in the core.

Comment: but I saw this one though https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/master/src/resources/views/fields/base64_image.blade.php and also this: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.4/crud-fields#base64_image can you confirm if this is not an actual feature?